# How to find which template is used in existing Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have one iOS application existing project and i have opened it in Xcode-7 but i want know which template is used in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, you can determine it by looking at the Story Board (`*.storyboard`, often `*` is `Main`).

Here we see the possible templates.

[image]

Then, how the typical story board layout looks for the...

1. Master-Detail Application

   [image]
2. Page-Based Application

   [image]
3. Single View Application

   [image]
4. Tabbed Application

   [image]
5. Game (which also features SpriteKit framework)

   [image]